# HealthKit Find Steps for today only

Tags: xcode, healthkit

I want to be able to find daily steps and put them into a variable from HealthKit. This is the code that I already have.

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()
```

I know it's not much but I wasn't able to find on the internet how to get the steps from today only, not average or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

An app is not allowed to read data from HealthKit without asking for permissions. So asking for relevant permission is the first step. To understand the flow, follow this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started)